# How to exclude user location from MKAnnotationView callout?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkmapview, mkannotation

I have the following code:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    if view.annotation is MKUserLocation {
        view.canShowCallout = false
    } else {
        self.locationInfoContainerView.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

I was hoping this would do the following: Show the container view when I tap annotation different than the user location.

What this code does, is shows the container view when I tap the USERLOCATION and not when I click annotation of other points on the map (So it does the exact opposite), I tried reversing the code like this:

```
  func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    if view.annotation is MKUserLocation {
        self.locationInfoContainerView.isHidden = false
    } else {
        view.canShowCallout = false    
    }
}
```

But this yields the same result. Can some shed some clarity on this and help me with programming the desired behavior? I.E: Showing the container view WHEN tapped on map annotation DIFFERENT than the user location on the map.

Hope this is clear enough, thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was:

```
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        if annotation is MKUserLocation {
            return nil 
        }
        :
        :
```

Answer (score 0):

Set title empty in `viewForAnnotation`

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
  if let userAnnotation = annotation as? MKUserLocation {
    userAnnotation.title = ""
    return nil
  }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry but this doesn't really solve anything for me. Thanks though! Cheers.